# HTML Documentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xmldocument

Is there a tool to generate HTML pages from XML Documentation files generated by VS2010?

I searched google for such a tool, but couldn't find one.

I downloaded and installed SandCastle, but I couldn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), it adds a UI over sandcastle :)

Comment: I'll admit this, I do not know how to use SandCastle. I do, however, know how to use SCHFB - and it works wonders!

Comment: Have you looked at the getting started section in the documentation? There's a full walkthrough... http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/b772e00e-1705-4062-adb6-774826ce6700.htm