# HTML Documentation, Part 2

Tags: c#, doxygen, sandcastle

Well, as suggested in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148210/html-documentation), I tried the GUI version of sandcastle and doxygen.

Unfortunately, it seems like I'm really bad at pressing buttons:

- Sandcastle:

  Generates a lot of HTM files with unrelated names, "compiles" them into a chm and deletes them. The CHM file does not contain the files at all! Just an index that leads to error pages.
- Doxygen:

  Generates perfectly good HTML, but from some reason, do not document all classes (Even though **ALL** class are documented, and so does all the methods and properties).

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doxygen you could try if it helps if you set EXTRACT_ALL to YES in the config file (it is under Expert->Build in the GUI).

If it does not help then please submit a bug report in doxygen's bug tracker (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen) 
and add a self-contained example (source+config file) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: EXTRACT_ALL was already marked, but I manually checked all boxes and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Re Sandcastle: please note that .chm files on newer versions of Windows are blocked by default. See
[How to display .chm content](http://didierdanse.net/blogs/dev_en/archive/2009/09/08/windows-7-how-to-display-chm-content.aspx)

Comment: Not the case, but thank you. The origin of the file is my computer, and when I checked the the properties of the file, there was no unblock button.

The CHM file is only 170 kB. Unlikely.